# Отправка POST запроса C#

Tags: c#, post

Мне необходимо сделать ПО для авторегистрации на одном из сайтов. Делаю подобное первый раз.

При попытке отправить пост запрос с данными на страницу регистрации, получаю ответ ошибка 405, как я понял ошибка связана с тем что на форме конечной страницы в `action` не указана страница обработчик запроса.

Вопрос, как найти куда уходит запрос при обычной(ручной) отправке данных с самой страницы?

Вот заголовок формы конечного сайта :

```
<form novalidate="" class="src-components-Form-styles--inline--1wVMU  -visor-no-click">
```

AJAX перехватывает? Давно не работал с веб, подскажите для чего в input

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="c0222 -metrika-nokeys" tabindex="0" id="firstname" data-cerber-id="registration_form::mail::name">
```

указано вот это `data-cerber-id="registration_form::mail::name"` и какую роль выполняет, часто на такое наталкиваюсь, ведь `data-cerber-id` зарезервированного такого не существует, верно?

Comment: У вас два разных вопроса. Ответ на первую часть: если action не указан - то отправка в ручном режиме идёт на тот же url. Как узнать, что перехватывается ajax - не знаю. По второму: можно создавать любые кастомные data- поля, логика зашитая в них разрабатывается в каждом случае отдельно. Поэтому для чего конкретно этот сайт сделал такое поле - надо у их программистов спрашивать. Ну или если повезёт, то может оказаться, что они сами его не пилили, а подключали стороннюю библиотеку к которой есть документация и вы почитаете, для чего это нужно. Ну либо сами реверсите логику сайта.

Comment: @AK data- поля для javascript или форма их так же передает на сервер? Если action не указан значит post запрос отправлять и нужно на эту же страницу, правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Отследи запрос с помощью Fiddler 4 и повтори его из своего приложения

Comment: Не могу понять как это сделать, подскажите? В главном окне вижу протокол, url, но куда уходить запрос не вижу